# How to change font size in 'Screen', the screen manager used by Limp to connect to SBCL?

Tags: vim, lisp, terminal, sbcl

I recently started using Lisp and Limp is the only available plugin for VIM. But, once I set it up and hit F12, the terminal like window that appears has a very small font size. I have a screen resolution of 1920x1080 and it's impractical to read such small fonts. I went through the man page of 'screen', but couldn't find any useful information on changing the font or font size. Is there a way to do this?

And how about using something like 'xterm' rather than 'screen'? I looked through the code of bridge.vim. I don't think it is too much of a task. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `screen`, do you mean [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/)?

GNU screen is a terminal emulator that runs in another terminal or emulator.  It has no direct control over font sizes; it's purely text based.  The window you're seeing must be some GUI terminal emulator; you haven't told us enough to guess which one (could be xterm, could be Gnome terminal, etc.).

For xterm, <kbd>control-right-click</kbd> should bring up the "VT Fonts" menu, which will let you select a different font.  If none of the available fonts are to your liking, you can use X resources to reconfigure the options, including the choice for the default font.

xterm also supports a control sequence that sets the current font.  You have to know the name of the font you want.  `xlsfonts` will show you a very long list of font names (it just showed me 5594 of them).  For example, if you run this from a shell running in xterm:

```
printf '\e]50;-misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--15-140-75-75-c-90-iso10646-1\a'
```

it should give you the font I usually use.  **But** `screen` generally intercepts escape sequences like that, so it probably won't work from `screen` under `xterm`.

Other terminal emulators should have similar mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me. I just changed xterm to gnome-terminal and it opens up with my favorite profile.